# How to make progress vertical bar increase instead of decrease

Tags: unity, image

I have a script for a vertical progress bar using filled image but the image decreases (basically you can see the full image when the game starts and then it goes down, like a health bar) but since it's a progress bar I need it to increase (at the end I should see the complete image, not at first). 
This is the code:

```
public class ProgressBar : MonoBehaviour {

public Image Bar;
public float max_progress = 100f;
public static float cur_progress = 0f;


void Start () {
    cur_progress = max_progress;
}

void Update () {
    Bar.fillAmount = cur_progress / max_progress;
}
```

And I have `ProgressBar.cur_progress -= 0.4f;` in the bullet script because it should increase everytime you kill an enemy.
I tried writing `+=` instead of `-=` but it doesn't work (the image is filled and it doesn't increase or decrease), and i think that is not incorrect so I don't know what the problem is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the line

```
cur_progress = max_progress;
```

from your `Start()` method. This is the part that currently says "Start 100% full."

Other than that, your idea to change the `ProgressBar.cur_progress` modification to `+=` is correct.